# Unity compute buffer that keeps track of the amount color in texture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hlsl, compute-shader

I've been trying to make a compute buffer that keeps track of track of the amount of pixels that have a certain color in my shader that creates procedural island textures.

This is a simplified version of my **compute shader**:

```
#pragma kernel CSMain

RWTexture2D<float4> Result;
RWStructuredBuffer<int> Biomes; // This buffer

float2 WorldSize;
float IslandSize;

[numthreads(8,8,1)]
void CSMain (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    float2 position = float2(id.x - WorldSize.x, id.y - WorldSize.y);
    float3 color = float3(0, 0, 1);

    float2 noise = generateNoise(position / IslandSize * 1000);
    float height = noise.x * 100;
    float falloff = noise.y;

    if (falloff < 1 && height < 5)
    {
        color = float3(0, 0.1, 1);
        InterlockedAdd(Biomes[1], 1); // Data gets added to the buffer
    }
    
    Result[id.xy] = float4(color, 1);
}
```

And here is my simplified **C# code** (biomes is a list of numbers of pixels that have a certain color in the texture), which is part of a function that gets called from `OnGUI()`:

```
// Set shader parameters
TerrainShader.SetVector("WorldSize", new Vector2(xSize, zSize));
TerrainShader.SetFloat("IslandSize", IslandSize * SizeMultiplier);

biomesBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(7, sizeof(int) * 7); // Buffer initialization
TerrainShader.SetBuffer(0, "Biomes", biomesBuffer);

// Dispatch compute shader
TerrainShader.SetTexture(0, "Result", target);
TerrainShader.Dispatch(0, xSize * 2, zSize * 2, 1);

// Get biome data
int[] biomes = new int[7];
biomesBuffer.GetData(biomes); // Retrieving data from buffer

string log = "";
for (int i = 0; i < biomes.Length; i++) {
    log += $"Biome {i}: {biomes[i]} ";
}
Debug.Log(log);

biomesBuffer.Dispose();
```

This is what my **console** looks like:

```
Biome 0: 2030086002 Biome 1: 0 Biome 2: 19020880 Biome 3: 52763400 Biome 4: 24948620 Biome 5: 16871260 Biome 6: 15926730
Biome 0: 1462274385 Biome 1: 0 Biome 2: 53590760 Biome 3: 148659300 Biome 4: 70291988 Biome 5: 47534272 Biome 6: 44873085
Biome 0: 843603332 Biome 1: 522 Biome 2: 37425056 Biome 3: 103816080 Biome 4: 49088343 Biome 5: 33195513 Biome 6: 31337076
Biome 0: 2030086002 Biome 1: 0 Biome 2: 19020880 Biome 3: 52763400 Biome 4: 24948620 Biome 5: 16871260 Biome 6: 15926730
Biome 0: 1462274385 Biome 1: 0 Biome 2: 53590760 Biome 3: 148659300 Biome 4: 70291988 Biome 5: 47534272 Biome 6: 44873085
...
```

I'm fairly new to compute shader and don't understand where these numbers are coming from. They should be the same in every new line of the console because the texture stays the same.

Here's what the **texture** looks like for reference:
[Compute shader result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlsnJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I believe your code should work apart from the fact that you're only ever setting to Biome[1] - the other numbers you're getting are random unset bits from memory.